# Why am I getting a "'str' object has no attribute 'execute'" error when I use Command.GET?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

using this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox
driver.get("WebDriver","https://www.youtube.com")
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Zohaib/PycharmProjects/FirstPyTesting/youtube.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver.get("WebDriver","http://localhost:81/")
  File "C:\Users\Zohaib\PycharmProjects\FirstPyTesting\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: `get` has only url parameter `driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")`.

Comment: then what i have to writer in parameters?

Comment: Just the url you want

Comment: The first thing you should always do is to look at [the docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#navigating)... or any tutorial out there.

Answer (score 1):

### get()

The [`get(url)`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get) method accepts an url in the form of a string and is defined as:

```
def get(self, url):
    """
    Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    """
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
```

---

### Solution

You you need to pass only the url in the form of a string as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```